# (Angular 2/4/5/6) Image recognition

Tags: angular, image-recognition

I would like to develop a functionality using angular 6 - after the user uploads an image, for example, of a phone, the system would be able to recognize the image and assign the device name and model number to it (based on data given in an excel spreadsheet).

May I know if this is possible? Would appreciate if someone could guide me or recommend any libraries. I've never done anything related to AI before - or scraping for images. Appreciate your help!

Comment: There is tensorflow.js https://www.tensorflow.org/js

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/

Comment: Maybe this article can help you:
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/tensorflow-js-quick-start/